# Change ItemsControl grouping dynamically

Tags: wpf, grouping, itemscontrol

I've search over the Internet for changing ItemsControl dynamically, but no luck (maybe my query is not good enough), so I ask here. Anyone can help me about creating grouping feature for an ItemsControl that can change group type dynamically. 
Example, I have a collection of songs which have properties: Name, Artirst, Singer, Album. Then I have 3 radio buttons to which property is used to group there songs.
I have thinked about creating multiple CollectionView, but I think there is another ways which is better.
(I'm new at WPF, so whould you please give a little more details answer. Thank you :))

Comment: clear the `GroupDescriptions` collection of `ICollectionView` and add a new `GroupDescription` to that collection.

Comment: @KingKing: thank you for your reply. Silly me, I don't think about it. Also, I think it helps binding easier.
But, may I ask another question, is that solution have a performance benefit? I think group and regrouping is an expensive task, especially with a large collection.

Comment: I don't think so, it's how you group an `ICollectionView`, it does the grouping for you internally, I'm also not sure what it does internally but it should be efficient as much as possible. Normally (implementing the grouping yourself) grouping is some kind of heavy task indeed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you please re-post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No I in fact do nothing, it's just a basic knowledge. If you care about the performance, you may want to try creating 3 different `CollectionView`s, each view grouped by a different property, then you just need to switch the `ItemsSource` to the corresponding view, also try adding more Threading stuff may improve the responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most minimal example I can come up with in MVVM style.

The viewmodel:

```
enum GroupBy
{
    Name,
    Artist
}

class Song
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
}

class SonglistViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     private GroupBy groupBy;

     public GroupBy GroupBy
     {
          get => this.groupBy;
          set 
          {
               if(this.groupBy == value)
               {
                    return;
               }

               this.groupBy = value;
               this.UpdateGrouping(value);
               this.OnPropertyChanged(); 
          }
     }

     public ObservableCollection<Song> Songs { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Song>();

     private void UpdateGrouping(GroupBy value)
     {
        var servicesView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Services);
        servicesView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
        switch (value)
        {
            case GroupBy.Name:
                servicesView.GroupDescriptions.Add(
                    new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(Song.Name)));
                break;

            case GroupBy.Artist:
                servicesView.GroupDescriptions.Add(
                    new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(Song.Artist)));
                break;
        }
    }         
}
```

The view:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
         <GroupStyle>
             <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount, StringFormat={}({0})}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListViewGroupStyle>
</ListView>
```